# Some audits became very easy to spot

Tags: bug, review-audits

There is a bug concerning the audits, which make them very easy to spot. They have a grayish look, as in the picture below. It must be added that this occurs only with some audits, not with all of them. This has been happening for the last two or three days.

[image]

Comment: cross-site duplicate https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429598/stuck-greyed-out-audits-and-non-upvotable-comments-bugs-in-review-queues and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429634/all-audits-grayed-out-by-design-or-bug

Comment: What exactly is the bug here? What is "very easy to spot"?

Comment: @Joachim If, in a review queue, I get a review with that persistent grayish look, I will know right away that it is an audit. It should not be that easy.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I mistook 'audit' for a synonym of 'review'.